# <video> tag in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, html, video

I am trying to add a video tag to a Sharepoint 2007 website with no success.

I created a new Content Editor webpart and injected this code:

http://pastebin.ca/2076724

```
<video id="movie" width="320" height="240" preload controls>
  <source src="/videos/test.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />

  <object id="MediaPlayer" width="320" height="240" CLASSID="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"
standby="Loading Windows Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject">
  <PARAM NAME="FileName" VALUE="http://www.domain.com/videos/test.wmv">
  <PARAM name="autostart" VALUE="false">
  <PARAM name="ShowControls" VALUE="true">
  <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="false">
  <PARAM name="ShowDisplay" VALUE="false">
  <EMBED TYPE="application/x-mplayer2" SRC="http://www.domain.com/videos/test.wmv" NAME="MediaPlayer"
  WIDTH="192" HEIGHT="190" ShowControls="1" ShowStatusBar="0" ShowDisplay="0" autostart="0"></EMBED>
  </OBJECT>
</video>
```

The controls are loaded, the video is found when doing Save Video (so no broken link), but the video does not play.

What I did is do Save Page As to my local disk, and tada: It works.

I fiddled with the code several times. I noticed that Sharepoint does alter the code a bit but the same code works when locally so..

I also do not have the HTML5 doctype in my website. (neither locally).

Ideas?

Comment: Just to verify, the same video and HTML snippet loads in a normal HTML page?

Comment: I did not try to create a normal HTML page what I did was to save the Sharepoint page to my drive and test it there. (I copied the code from an html5 book and cross-checked it with other examples so I'm pretty sure it's bulletproof..)

Comment: Well, you should test that your browser has support for that video.

Comment: I have the browsers compatibility tables and it does, besides the same browser plays the video when server from my local hdd drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What MIME type is Sharepoint serving the video as?  It should be `video/ogg`, [here's a Technet article on how to configure MIME types in IIS6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cd72c0dc-c5b8-42e4-96c2-b3c656f99ead.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: I checked Firebug, in the "Net" tab and I see this in the video response headers: 
Response Headers 
Content-Type **application/octet-stream**
Last-Modified Wed, 08 Jun 2011 15:41:08 GMT
Etag "{77150F04-D55B-4F3E-8176-613938D13473},2"
Server Microsoft-IIS/6.0

Comment: Actually, I changed the video format to WEBM, and the video worked on Google Chrome, (still not working in Firefox 4.x) so I am guessing it's a client-side problem.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos Your content type needs to be `video/ogg` (or now `video\webm`) for it to work in Firefox - if the file received is not the correct content type it won't play.  Chrome is evidentally doing some content sniffing.